# C# COM vs C++ COM return value

Tags: c#, c++, com, com-interop

I'm building a COM component C#, the customer can set binary data. It would be nice if the COM component returns exception rather than error code, but realized it would be difficult to handle exception in (Delphi, C + + and JScritp). I chose it receives a data in hexadecimal (internally convert to binary) and return in hexadecimal (internally convert binary to hexadecimal).
 The method getData can return the data and a error code, the question is: how to do this in C# interop?

in C++ COM exists the HRESULT

```
HRESULT getData([in] int __position, [out,retval] BSTR* __data); // can Return __data or error -1 data not exists
HRESULT setData([in] BSTR __data, [out,retval] int* __status);
```

but in C# COM ??

```
int getData ??? // return __status or __data;
int setData(String __data); // return __status;
```

thanks in advanced,

Comment: Where is your problem? There's no question here.

Comment: I tried to amend the wording.

Comment: I think you are trying to ask, how do you control the HRESULT value in a COM Interface method.  See my answer below.

Comment: @Shane Powell, Sorry for the confusion, not handle but throw. I would like to return error code or data. Exception solve, but it is difficult to capture C# Interop COM exception in Delphi, C++ and JScript.

Comment: Exceptions is how .net runtime handle COM HRESULTS (that are errors).  .net runtime converts HRESULT values to from/to exceptions.  How the COM client handles HRESULT is up to language runtime.  In C++ you just get the HRESULT and you have to handle it.  In other runtimes it will differ.

Comment: "I would like to return error code or data" You cannot return either/or in the same slot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return an `HRESULT` from each COM method and return the data in `out` parameters. However, the COM interop layer shields this from you by automatically translating between COM `HRESULT` error codes and C# exceptions.  I think your code should really look like this:

**MIDL**

```
HRESULT getData([out,retval] BSTR* pData);
HRESULT setData([in] BSTR data);
```

**C#**

```
String getData();
void setData(String data);
```

The key point is that the COM function return value is always an `HRESULT`.  If the function succeeds then `S_OK` is returned—otherwise you an appropriate error code that describes the reason for failure is returned. The true return value, `data` in this example, is returned through an out parameter rather than the return value.  But of course, the COM interop layer hides that implementation detail from you.

Your question appears to suggest that you wish for the return value to be either an `HRESULT` in case of failure, or a string in case of success.  This is not possible since function return values are statically typed.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I need. Thus, the method may return error code or data. Sorry for my vague question.

Comment: Technically you return both error code and data but data only means something when error code is S_OK.

Comment: S_OK in C#? I did not understand. I tryed here, return data and -1 and works (C# to C++), I will return 0 if ok.

Comment: `int getData(out String __data);` will look in COM as `HRESULT getData([out] BSTR* __data, [out, retval] int*)`, as in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367158%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. You cannot mix the COM HRESULT semantics with the C# method return value, they represent different things.

Comment: Your own post uses the same convention, does it not? Point is that the c++ signature will take the `int` return of C# as an output parameter (int*), not as the return C/C++ value. You cannot return an int in C# (S_OK) and expect this to be the HRESULT value seen by the COM caller.

Comment: @remus that's not at all what I'm trying to say. Also in this getData function the true retval is the string rather than an int. So I believe it should read: `HRESULT getData([out,retval] BSTR* __data)`

Comment: @Remus I've tried to explain it better now. I think a lot of the confusion is caused by the translation between the HRESULT free C# code and the MIDL code which includes the explicit HRESULT return values.

Comment: This is much better. I read your original reply as 'you can return an int with value 0 (=S_OK) in C# and will be the HRESULT seen in C++ code` which was clearly wrong.

Comment: @Remus I'm a out of my depth on the C# COM stuff never having used it, but I do know what it's like from C++ and Delphi, hence the somewhat sloppy early version.

Comment: @David Heffernan RemusRusanu. This means I can not use: public int getData(out String ret)
        {
            ret = "data";
            throw new Exception();
            return -1;
        } in c#?

Comment: @Cobaia Between us we've answered your question. Your latest comment makes no sense at all. You can't return a value from a function that raises an exception. Do you understand that the C# COM layer converts exceptions into HRESULT?

Comment: @Cobaia Good! It's quite hard to work all these things out in comments!

Answer (score 6):

C# maps known C# exceptions to HRESULT values.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ztbc5s1.aspx) is Microsoft's documentation on the mapping list.  You can get further control by throwing a [COMException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comexception.aspx).

Comment: Hi @Shane Powell. You are saying I can throw an exception in C# Interop and capture in (Delphi, C++ and JScript) ?

Comment: No, I'm saying that you throw an exception and the .net runtime converts it to a HRESULT return value.  How the HRESULT COM value is interrupted on the other side is up to them.  For example in C++ you get the raw HRESULT value, if called from C# it will convert the HRESULT back into a exception.  I don't know what happens in Delphi or JScript, you will have to look up how those languages interop with COM.

Comment: use safecall in delphi and the HRESULT will be transformed into an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Just throw an exception in C#. The C# interop layer will know how to catch the exception, return a E_FAIL hresult (or other appropriate value if the C# exception is known or a [COMException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comexception.aspx) that specifies the value explicitly) and setup the [`IErrorInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723041%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on your COM object. The C++ smart COM pointers like [`_com_ptr_t`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/417w8b3b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) know how to handle this case and will raise an appropriate C++ exception.

See [Handling COM Interop Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awy7adbx.aspx).

Comment: in C# i did public int getData(out String ret){ ret = "data"; throw new Exception(); return -1;} in C++ try
  {
   BSTR test; 
   int error = objCOM->getData(&test);
  }
  catch(exception e)
  {

  }. But not works.

Comment: is objCom a smart pointer (_com_ptr_t) or a raw pointer? A row pointer has to go the long route (query interface for IErrorInfo and then ask the error infor from there). Use a smart pointer and will take care of the details for you.

Comment: Actually I may remember things wrong. _com_ptr_t does not throw automatically, you still need to check the HRESULT and raise an _com_Error explcitly. See http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/259/the-same-if-block-over-and-over-again-oh-my

Comment: thanks, i tried with CComPtr but Unhandled exception at 0x7c812afb, this is my code: HRESULT errorCheck;
 ATL::CComPtr<IMyClassCOM> objCOM;
 CoInitialize(NULL);
 errorCheck = objCOM.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_MyClassCOM, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER);

 if (SUCCEEDED(errorCheck))
 {
  try
  {
   BSTR test; 
   int error = objCOM->getData(&test);
  }
  catch(exception e) ... C# throw new Exception, C++ can't handle. C# code: public int getData(out String ret)
        {
            ret = "data";
            throw new Exception();
            return -1;
        }

Comment: CComPtr throws CAtlException I think, so `catch(exception e)` will not work because CAtlException is not derived from std::exception. Try adding a `catch(CAtlExceptio& e)` and/or a `catch(...)` in the C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
[DllImport(DllName)]
static extern int getData(int __position, StringBuilder __data);
```

Comment: Hi @SwDevMan81. I'm not using c++ dll, I only want to write a method thats can return (String or Error code) in C# COM. Thanks.

Comment: @Cobaia - To return two values you could use a KeyValuePair (like here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/multiple-return-values).  Or you can assign values to the parameters using the 'out' keyword

Comment: `DLLImport` and `StringBuilder` are not appropriate here. This is COM interop rather than P/invoke.